# apache2: Get a list of registered handlers

Tags: apache-2.2, handler-mappings

Is it possible, to get a list of all handlers from apache? With [setHandler](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#sethandler) it is possible to create handlers.

One possible usage would be to add a handler for a specific file extension ([addHandler](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_mime.html#addhandler)). Knowing all the possible handlers and their identifier would ease the process of matching them to a file extension (or in case of URL handlers creating a list of possible URLs).

The handlers must be managed in apache core in some kind of list - how is it possible to get this list out?

Answer (score 4):

**Apache does not expose a list of configured handlers.** Not using `apachectl`, not with anything else.

The best method that I could find to **get a list of configured handlers** is to simply grep the Apache configuration folder for `Handler` to catch all `AddHandler` and `SetHandler` declarations.

### For Debian-based (Ubuntu) hosts

```
$ grep -ir "Handler" /etc/apache2/*
mods-enabled/php5.conf: SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
mods-enabled/php5.conf: SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-source
apache2.conf:           SetHandler server-status
mods-available/info.conf:    SetHandler server-info
mods-available/ldap.conf:    SetHandler ldap-status
mods-available/status.conf:  SetHandler server-status
mods-available/php5.conf:    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
mods-available/php5.conf:    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-source
sites-available/default:     AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
sites-enabled/000-default:   AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
```

### For Redhat-based (Fedora, CentOS) hosts

```
$ grep -ir "Handler" /etc/httpd/*
conf.d/php.conf:  AddHandler php5-script .php
conf/httpd.conf:  #AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
conf/httpd.conf:  #AddHandler send-as-is asis
conf/httpd.conf:  AddHandler type-map var
conf/httpd.conf:  #ErrorDocument 404 "/cgi-bin/missing_handler.pl"
conf/httpd.conf:     AddHandler type-map var
conf/httpd.conf:#    SetHandler server-status
conf/httpd.conf:#    SetHandler server-info
conf.d/fcgid.conf:   AddHandler fcgid-script fcg fcgi fpl
conf.d/perl.conf:#   SetHandler perl-script
conf.d/perl.conf:#   SetHandler perl-script
```

**Note that not all handlers found are in fact registered!** Search in `mods-enabled` (Debian) and disregard lines starting with `#` to narrow down only the registered handlers.

As suggested by Jenny in the comments, **commented lines can be removed** by filtering the output with `grep -Pv '^[^ ]*:\s*#'`. Here is the final command for Debian-based machines:

```
$ grep -ir "Handler" /etc/apache2/* | grep -Pv '^[^ ]*:\s*#'
```

And for Redhat-based machines:

```
$ grep -ir "Handler" /etc/httpd/* | grep -Pv '^[^ ]*:\s*#'
```

In the comments user [gogoud](https://serverfault.com/users/274209/gogoud) provides an additional way to strip out commented handlers, thus returning only registered handlers:

```
// Debian or Ubuntu
$ grep -R "Handler" /etc/apache2/*enabled* | sed 's/#.*//;/^[^:]*:\s*$/d'

// Redhat, CentoOS, Fedora
$ grep -R "Handler" /etc/httpd/*enabled* | sed 's/#.*//;/^[^:]*:\s*$/d'
```

Comment: To get rid of the commented-out handlers, use some find and grep magic: `find /etc/httpd/ -type f -exec grep -H -v '#' {} \; | grep Handler`

Comment: @JennyD: I think that would remove lines with comments after the declarations, such as `AddHandler cgi-script .cgi # Ben needs CGI`.

Comment: True. You could do it with `egrep` and a suitable regexp, which is left as an exercise for the reader (as unfortunately I have to do some paid work right now...)

Comment: @JennyD: Challenge accepted! I've added a grep filter for commented lines. Nice thinking, thanks!

Comment: Why the sudden downvotes? This answer directly answers the question and even includes examples for the two most common Linux variants. If the answer could be improved I would appreciate some _constructive_ criticism.

Comment: For Debian this will show only *enabled* handlers, stripping comments whether on their own line or at the end of declaration lines: `grep -R "Handler" /etc/apache2/*enabled* | sed 's/#.*//;/^[^:]*:\s*$/d'`

Answer (score 0):

This is isn't quite what you want, but if you enable the `server-info` handler in your config, the output will tell you which modules have handlers and which don't, like this:

```
Module Name: mod_negotiation.c
Content handlers: yes
....
Module Name: mod_mime.c
Content handlers: none
....
```

This was with Apache 2.2, so perhaps later versions will give you more useful output.

Comment: Thank you, however I'm not seeing that info. [This page](http://192.117.111.61/apache.html) shows the output of `server-info`. Do note, however, that the output is a static page copied from the real server and served to you via a Raspberry Pi.